# AngularJS share data between nested components properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to embed a nested component in a page.

> *(A page is actually a controller that can be reached via the `$routeProvider` service)*

And I want to bring data from the main component to its child component and vice versa - in order to make all of the components in the page and the page itself talking with each other in a full data binding.

I success to send data from parent to child with specific bindings attributes, however, I am not getting a way to bring data from child to parent.

```
// lobby.js - the main page.
// we can reach this page via browser by the $routeProvider service

app.config(($routeProvider) => {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/", {
    templateUrl : "screens/lobby/lobby.html"
  })
});

app.controller("lobby", ($scope, datepickerService) => {

  $scope.title = "Welcome to Lobby screen!";

  $scope.order = {};

  $scope.send = function() {
    console.log($scope.order);
  };

});
```

Lobby.html

```
<!-- This is lobby.html file -->
<!-- Which is the html template of the main page (lobby.js) -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="screens/lobby/lobby.css">

<div class="lobby" ng-controller="lobby">

  <date-picker type="default" model="startDate"></date-picker>
  <date-picker type="default" model="endDate"></date-picker>

  <button type="button" name="button" ng-click="send()">Send</button>

</div>
```

Now as you can see, in the lobby.html file I have a nested component which is `<date-picker></date-picker>`. From parent I pass to this child component two attributes: `type` and `model`.

Now lets see this component functionality:

```
// datepicker.js component (actually defined as a directive)
// Initializing a datepicker plugin from jQuery UI Lib.

app.directive("datePicker", (datepickerService) => {
  return {
    templateUrl: "/shared/datepicker/datepicker.html",
    scope: {
      model: "@",
      type: "@",
    },
    link: function(scope, elements, attrs) {

      $(function() {
        setTimeout(function () {
          $("." + scope.model).datepicker({
            onSelect: function(value) {
              value = datepickerService.correct(value);
              $("." + scope.model).val(value);
              console.log(value);
            }
          });
        }, 200);
      });

    }
  }
});
```

datepicker.html

```
<!-- datepicker.html the datepicker html template -->
<!-- Successfuly getting the datepicker to be loaded and work -->

<box ng-show="type=='default'">
  <input type="text" class="{{model}}" readonly>
</box>
```

Now the problem: notice the:

```
// lobby.js
$scope.send = function() {
  console.log($scope.order);
};
```

in the lobby.js file.

I need this to send the actual `startDate` and `endDate` to a remote server. However I cannot access this data! `$scope.order` remains blank.

I have tried using components instead of directives I have tried `ng-include` I have tried more lot of things that I wont bother you with, since I have spent on it more than 3 days.

How can I work with nested components so all of the data will be shared through each of them, including the main page in AngularJS in order to create a scaleable modern app?

Thanks.

Comment: Mixing jQuery with AngularJS like this is asking for problems. Consider using an AngularJS plugin like [uib-datepicker-popup](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!datepickerPopup), a Bootstrap component written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team.

Answer (score 1):

For sending data from parent to child angular provides the `$broadcast()` method and for sending data from child to parent it provides the `$emit()` method.

**More info:**
http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/5d8be0b6-e294-457e-82b0-ba7cc10cae0e.aspx

Comment: Best.
Works as accepted. I wait just more to see if there more good answers, if no I will mark yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to reference your startDate and endDate within your order object. Right now it seems you save those directly on your $scope.
Try this to verify:

```
console.log($scope.order, $scope.startDate, $scope.endDate);
```

add "**order.**" in front your objects within the ***model*** attribute.

```
<!-- This is lobby.html file -->
<!-- Which is the html template of the main page (lobby.js) -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="screens/lobby/lobby.css">

<div class="lobby" ng-controller="lobby">

   <date-picker type="default" model="order.startDate"></date-picker>
   <date-picker type="default" model="order.endDate"></date-picker>

   <button type="button" name="button" ng-click="send()">Send</button>

</div>
```

Also, you might also need to change the attribute definition of your component to use bidirectional binding. Use "**=**" instead of "**@**". @ only represents a copy of the value when getting passed to your component and not saved back to the original object.

```
...
scope: {
  model: "=",
  type: "@",
},
...
```

**Update**:

Please find my working Plunker here https://embed.plnkr.co/2TVbcplXIJ01BMJFQbgv/

Comment: When using "=" I do not able to receive the actual data comming from the parent component. I receive an "undefined".

Comment: you also have to set the value back to your scope variable "model".
I attached a plunker example